# How to implement lazy load or load on scroll in React

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

Hello i have list of objects I want to implement lazy load or load on scroll for this list since its long list and each object take time to load which make the application super slow to list aloof them one shot

the code

```
const TrackList = ({ classes, tracks }) => (
  <List>
    {tracks.map(track => (
      <ExpansionPanel key={track.id}>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
          <ListItem className={classes.root}>
            {/* <LikeTrack /> */}
            <ListItemText 
              primaryTypographyProps={{
                variant: "subheading",
                color: 'primary'
              }} 
              primary={track.title}
              // secondary={
              //   <Link 
              //       className={classes.link}
              //       to={`/profile/${track.postedBy.id}`}>
              //     {track.postedBy.username}
              //   </Link>
              // }
              />
              <AudioPlayer url={track.url}/>
          </ListItem>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <Typography
            variant="body1">
              {track.description}
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        {/* <ExpansionPanelActions>
          <UpdateTrack />
          <DeleteTrack />
        </ExpansionPanelActions> */}
      </ExpansionPanel>
    ))}
  </List>

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass only first e.g. 20 tracks to `TrackList` component.
When you scroll to the bottom of the list, pass both first and second batch of 20 tracks, etc. in a way "appending" (not quite accurate term here) the items to the list.

If you list is huge and performance is crucial, use [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized).